# html form-- need help having new input area populate if radio button is clicked

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql

I am making a basic new customer database with mysql and php. I would like when people click on the radio button"different mailing address" for another couple of input fields to appear for the mailing address. Im not quite sure how to handle this with inputs and not variables. Is there a way to do an if statement here is my html form code below

```
    <form method="POST" action="insert.php">
    <fieldset>
    <legend>New Customer data</legend>
    <label>Complete Below</label>

<div class="controls controls-row">
  <input class="span4" name="firstname" type="text" placeholder="First name">
  <input class="span3" name="lastname" type="text" placeholder="Last Name">
   <input class="span3" name="phone" type="text" placeholder="Phone">

</div>
<div class="controls controls-row">
  <input class="span4" name="address" type="text" placeholder="Address">
  <input class="span2" name="city" type="text" placeholder="City">
  <input class="span1" name="state" type="text" placeholder="State">
</div>
<div class="controls controls-row">
  <input class="span4" name="zip" type="text" placeholder="Zip Code">
  <input class="span2" name="email" type="text" placeholder="Email">
  <input class="span2" name="ccemail" type="text" placeholder="cc email">
</div>





    <span class="help-block">When is the customers due date monthly</span>
      <label class="radio">
  <input type="radio" name="duedate" id="optionsRadios1" value="1" checked>
 1st of the month</label>
<label class="radio">
  <input type="radio" name="duedate" id="optionsRadios2" value="15">
 15th of the month
 </label>    
  <span class="help-block">Mailing address</span>
 <label class="radio">
  <input type="radio" name="mailingaddress" id="optionsRadios3" value="1" checked>
Check if mailing address is the same as the service address
</label>
<label class="radio">
  <input type="radio" name="mailingaddress" id="optionsRadios4" value="0">
 Check if mailing address is different
 </label>

                     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>



  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: You will probably need some jacascript to either hide fields or show them depending on selection or create them based on selection. Judging by your question I think you're looking for a php solution which will not work as php is server side. Meaning you cannot monitor interaction without a page refresh.

Comment: You added the jquery tag to your question... maybe jquery can help you with this?

Comment: I think you need to go read about JavaScript and jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery, have two inputs that are initially hidden. Once the user checks the box, '$.show()' on those two inputs. Id have a div containing two inputs, and just show or hide the div depending on whether the box is checked or not

Answer (score 0):

you can try this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js" >
</script>
<script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
 $("#checkme").on('change',function(){
    if($("#checkme").is(":checked")){
        $("input#myemail").fadeIn();
    }else{
        $("input#myemail").fadeOut();
    }
 });
   });
</script>
</head>
<body>
show: <input type="checkbox" id="checkme" /><br />
<input type="text" id="myemail" hidden />
</body>
</html>
```